# NSFetchedResultsController ERROR: The fetched object at index X has an out of order section name Y. Objects must be sorted by section name'

Tags: ios4, sorting, core-data, uisearchbar

I'm implementing search bar in iphone app. I have list of Workers, each have attributes: firstName, lastName, company. Sections of table view are set to company attribute.

I did set predicate when searching:

```
NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName contains[cd] %@", searchBar.text];
```

and i get error:

```
NSFetchedResultsController ERROR: The fetched object at index 3 has an out of order section name 'company2. Objects must be sorted by section name'
```

when I have sortDescriptor:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

I did notice that when I change it to

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstName"` ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

now search works correctly with no error. Does initWithKey param must match attribute name in predicate? I don't get it.

Comment: Are you using a NSFetchedResultsController?

Comment: yes, I'm using NSFetchedResultsController.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the NSFetchedResultsController docs:

> The fetch request must have at least
>   one sort descriptor. If the controller
>   generates sections, the first sort
>   descriptor in the array is used to
>   group the objects into sections; its
>   key must either be the same as
>   sectionNameKeyPath or the relative
>   ordering using its key must match that
>   using sectionNameKeyPath.

In your case, you need to use two sorts (in an array.) Element one should be a sort on the company name attribute and second element should sort on the lastName/firstName attribute.